# Can a person on a US tourist visa receive compensation for participating in a medical trial?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, work

A relative of mine has recently arrived in the US on a B1/B2 visa, which normally prohibits any kind of work in the US. They've signed up for a COVID-related trial and have been accepted. Said trial offers a small (few hundred dollars) compensation for participating, which would be a nice bonus in addition to helping the medical community. The trial organizers do not care about the participant's visa status, as long as you can report back a couple of times in the future.

Is it legal for someone on a B1/B2 to receive money for participating in a medical trial? Or should my relative participate while refusing payment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few online references to policy and procedures for the researchers conducting clinical trials with human subjects. Most deal with the taxation paperwork required to satisfy the IRS (such as 35% witholding) and do not touch on visa status. There is also a wide variation in policies, indicating that this is more than a bit of grey area, such as a "recent" reclassification of human subjects as not independent contractors.

The closest I could find to answering your question is [this](https://hr.vanderbilt.edu/international-tax/pymts_human_subject_participants.php) one from Vanderbilt University that states that non-Vanderbilt-sponsored H1-B participants cannot receive remuneration but can participate.

> International persons (business visitors) receiving payments for
> compensation as human subject participants are required to complete
> the online Business Visitor Questionnaire (BVQ) and allow the ITO to
> create an international tax record before payment will be issued. The
> online BVQ can be found here.  Note again that persons in H-1B status
> who have not been sponsored by Vanderbilt University, cannot receive
> compensation for human subject participation. These persons may
> participate in clinical or research studies but no compensation can be
> provided as this violates the terms of their H-1B visa status.
>
> Vanderbilt-sponsored H-1B employees, however, can receive compensation
> since they hold an employment relationship with Vanderbilt.

Probably, declining payment would be the prudent course if they decide to participate. Maybe request that it be donated to a food bank or other charity in the name of the University.